# How to target sibling DIV node in XPath

Tags: xpath

I have this html code:

```
<div class="info">
    <div class="label">Phone</div>
    <div class="text">+966 (13) 828 3771</div>
</div>
```

Using XPath, I need to target the Text inside div class text.

For now, I'm using this code and I can target the div class label:

```
.//*[@class="label"]/text()[contains(.,"Phone")]
```

How could I target the text inside `<div class="text">`?

There are other `<div class="info">` and `<div class="label">`, and I need to target those that are direct sibling of `<div class="label">` that contains `Phone` in it.

Answer (score 0):

`//div[@class = 'info' and div[@class = 'label' and contains(., 'Phone')]]/div[@class = 'text']` should select the `div` element(s) with the `class` attribute `text` inside a `div` parent element that has the `class` attribute `info` and a child `div` with `class` as `label` and which contains the text `Phone`.

Comment: I've tried it but it does not work using an online XPath Tester. It kinda works only if the exact html code block is copied, but not when the whole page is tested - Thanks though.

Comment: Well you need to show the real HTML then in your question.